# How to copy webResources in Maven

Tags: maven

I am using maven as the build tool. I have an web application. I want to create another web application,all the xhtml pages in first web application should get copied to the new application.But there are some exceptions.If a file by name say login.xhtml exists in both old & new application then the one in new application should prevail.In the maven war plugin using some exclusion rules I can make it work(it is actually in that state), but I am looking for a cleaner solution so that everytime a new file by same name is introduced in both the applications, I do not have to hardcode the exclusion rule in POM.I also tried by using dependency- that is the new application is dependent on the war of old one, but there timestamp is winning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do your work by using Maven overlays

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html

> An overlay of a WAR file, is simply a Maven project that uses another
>   project's WAR output as a dependency, rather than a project's JAR.
>   When the overlay project is built, the underlying project's WAR file
>   is exploded and files in the overlay project added to it. If an
>   overlay project has a file with the same path and name as a file in
>   the underlying WAR it will replace it.

You can also follow this [step-by-step guide](https://github.com/iipc/openwayback/wiki/Creating-a-WAR-overlay).